# Особый синтаксис для разбиения матрицы на секцию

Tags: python, numpy

Имеется некая матрица numpy, и на ее основе создается секция с помощью следующего кода:`matrix[:, row_from:row_to, col_from:col_to]` ,
где row_from, row_to, col_from и col_to - константы.
Как работает данный синтаксис?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Матрица, заданная таким образом, является фактически 3d-массивом с размерностью **X** на **Y** на **Z**, который иначе можно представить как **Z** 2d-массивов с размерностью X на Y каждый. Параметры среза в numpy-массиве работают так же, как и в собственно питоне - первым идет идентификатор 2d-массива, затем собственно срез внутри каждого массива по строкам и столбцам.

```
arr = np.arange(27).reshape((3,3,3))
```

представляет собой матрицу такого типа:

```
#столбцы              0  1  2
#массив 0  ряд 0  [[[ 0  1  2] 
#          ряд 1    [ 3  4  5]  
#          ряд 2    [ 6  7  8]] 

#массив 1  ряд 0   [[ 9 10 11] 
#          ряд 1    [12 13 14] 
#          ряд 2     [15 16 17]]

#массив 2  ряд 0   [[18 19 20] 
#          ряд 1    [21 22 23]   
#          ряд 2    [24 25 26]]]
```

представленный вами срез расшифровывается так:

```
: - все массивы матрицы (не указаны начало и конец диапазона вокруг двоеточия)
row_from:row_to - ряды с row_from (включая) до row_to (не включая)
col_from:col_to - столбцы с col_from (включая) до col_to (не включая)
```

Для нашей матрицы срез вида arr[:,1:2,1:2] даст следующее:

```
[[[ 4]]

 [[13]]

 [[22]]]
```

То есть, значения всех трех 2d-массивов c первого (включительно) по второй (не включая) ряды и с первого (включительно) по второй (не включая) столбцы. То есть - средние элементы массивов.

Аналогично вы можете выбрать не все массивы матрицы, а только, например, два последних:

```
arr[1:,:,:]
```

даст нам все значения массивов матрицы начиная с первого массива:

```
[[[ 9 10 11]
  [12 13 14]
  [15 16 17]]

 [[18 19 20]
  [21 22 23]
  [24 25 26]]]
```

То есть, ничего *особого* в этом синтаксисе нет. Вам просто нужно понять для себя "геометрию" матрицы.